# The question of every vector space has a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

The proof of this theorem at wiki is that

> Let $V$ be any vector space over some field $F$. Let $X$ be the set of all linearly independent subsets of $V$.
> The set $X$ is nonempty since the empty set is an independent subset of $V$, and it is partially ordered by inclusion, which is denoted, as usual, by $\subseteq$.
> Let $Y$ be a subset of $X$ that is totally ordered by $\subseteq$, and let $L_Y$ be the union of all the elements of $Y$, Therefore, $L_Y$ is an upper bound for Y.

my question is

$Y$ is chain in $X$, if $Y$ has infinite elements, then the union of $Y$ is infinite union,
how to understand the infinite union is the upper bound of $Y$?

Comment: For any collection of subsets $S_i$ of a set $X$, the union of all the $S_i$ (which is a subset of $X$) is a least upper bound (with respect to inclusion) for the collection. Finiteness either of the collection or of its elements is not required. So the only question that might remain is whether here that union is linearly independent (which it is, easily, as any linear dependence involves only a finite number of elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realise the types at play here:

$Y$ is a subset of $X$, which is the set of all linearly independent subsets of $V$. So $Y$ is a set of subsets of $V$ as well. So $A \in Y$ implies $A \subseteq V$ and also that $A$ is linearly independent.

So the union $L_Y$ is also a well-defined subset of $V$; recall it's definition:

$$v \in L_Y \iff \exists A \in Y: v \in A\tag{1}$$

So existence follows directly from the union axiom of ZFC (if you want to be that formal).

And for any $A \in Y$ we clearly have $A \subseteq L_Y$ (if $v \in A$ we just pick $A$ itself as the "witness" in $(1)$ to see $v \in L_Y$ as well). And because the order on $X$ is $\subseteq$ (!) we have that $L_Y$ is an upper bound for $Y$: it's at least as big as each element of $Y$.

The only thing left to verify is that indeed $L_Y \in X$ (so it's a valid *element* of the poset $(X, \subseteq)$) which means we have to check that $L_Y$ is linearly independent in $V$. But this is not so hard, Kavi already hinted to the proof of that fact.

Comment: thanks! u are still here.

Comment: @maplgebra yep I am, why?

Answer (score 1):

If the union is linearly dependent then some finite linear combination $\sum a_iv_i$ vanishes without all the coefffcients being $0$. Note that all the $v_i$'s lie in one member of the chain. Hence we have a contradiction.

Comment: actually i mean the existence of infinite union.

Comment: I have shown that the union, even if it is infinite union, is linearly independent. It  obviously contains each member of the chain.